# Google Webmaster tools, hide domain url without hiding its childs

Tags: google-search-console

I have a domain foo.imap.cc and i created a website under foo.imap.cc/website/.

I would like to hide foo.imap.cc from google indexing with out removing foo.imap.cc/website/

I tried stuff like google robots, but google is not detecting my robots file. I also noticed that if I remove the url foo.imap.cc with the url removing tool from webmaster tools all its childs are removed.

For the moment my solution is to redirect the url foo.imap.cc to foo.imap.cc/website/ but I don't really like this solution because I'm having some problems with the indexing title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google should not be ignoring your robots.txt file and probably isn't. Robots.txt files do *not* prevent search engines from indexing pages in a website. It just prevents crawlers from accessing blocked pages. Pages blocked in robots.txt can still appear in the search results.

To prevent search engines from indexing content in your main directory but not the subdirectorty, use [`x-robots-tag`](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html) in two .htaccess files. One in the root web directory to block it, and another to explicitly allow it (by overriding the root rule) in the subdirectory.

Root web directory .htaccess file:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

Subdirectory .htaccess file:

```
X-Robots-Tag: index
```